# how to setup pixelSearch only in middle of window mode screen

Tags: autohotkey

im playing ragnarok using macro.. my script is doing good.. but how can i pixelsearch/attack only the middle area? im using 1024 x 768 game window mode, using the CoordMode, Pixel, Relative

[image: http://i60.tinypic.com/t681md.png]

```
CoordMode, Pixel, Relative
CoordMode, Mouse, Relative


    Home:: ;click home to start

       Loop  {
    PixelSearch, X, Y, 0, 0, %A_ScreenWidth%, %A_ScreenHeight%, 0x00FF00, 0, fast  ;<--- this is the color of green boxed monsters to attack
    if(ErrorLevel=0) {
    MouseClick, left, %X%, %Y%
     }
    else {

        Send {F1}   ; <--- if no monster present in screen, press teleport to search monsters


         }
    }
    return

    PgUp::Pause
    End::ExitApp
```

Answer (score 0):

As I commented in your previous question:

`0, 0, %A_ScreenWidth%, %A_ScreenHeight%` are coordinates. Replace these with any nubers (preferably with any variable contents) you like. Measure your exact coordinates with with WindowSpy. Open WindowSpy by right-clicking on any AHK script in the taskbar and selecting it. I suggest you then also take a look at [coordmode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/CoordMode.htm).

Documentation says:

> PixelSearch, OutputVarX, OutputVarY, X1, Y1, X2, Y2, ColorID [, Variation, Fast|RGB]
>
> X1, Y1    The X and Y coordinates of the upper left corner of the rectangle to search
>
> X2, Y2    The X and Y coordinates of the lower right corner of the rectangle to search

You are using: `PixelSearch, X, Y, 0, 0, %A_ScreenWidth%, %A_ScreenHeight%`. So, the coordinates of your selected rectangle's upper left corner are `0|0` and the lower right corner's are `%A_ScreenWidth%|%A_ScreenHeight%`. Let's assume your screen is 1366 pixels broad and 768 pixels wide. Then, the coordinates of the lower right corner are `1366|768`.

You can replace these numbers with anything you like, for example

```
PixelSearch, X, Y, 300, 100, 600, 200, 0x00FF00, 0, fast
```

, or preferably

```
upperLeftX := 300
upperLeftY := 100
lowerRightX := 600
lower RightY := 200
PixelSearch, X, Y, %upperLeftX%, %upperLeftY%, %lowerRightX%, %lowerRightY%, 0x00FF00, 0, fast
```

(which is the same as above),

where `300|100` are the coordinates of the upper left corner and `600|200` the coordinates of the lower right corner for PixelSearch to search for your Pixel in. Determine the coords of your preference with WindowSpy.

Comment: http://i60.tinypic.com/33jsbiw.png ok heres my windows spy.. im using relative coordmode.. the red highlighted box is the middle where i hover my mouse to see the coordinates in windowspy.. the coordinates are 500,166 ,where should i put those coords?

Comment: read the description of PixelSearch ( https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/PixelSearch.htm ), it explains it perfectly

Comment: im really confuse to it so i ask for help >.<. could you make me example of script

Comment: did it work now? do you understand how to approach it?